# On back button, how to display fragment defined in XML layout after it's been replaced by another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an activity whose layout includes a fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
            android:name="com.MyMainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

On a button click, the main fragment is replaced with fragment B:

```
public void diplayFragmentB() {

    Fragment mainFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .hide(mainFragment) 
            .commit();

    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB);
    transaction.commit();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
```

When the user clicks on back button, a blank screen is displayed instead of the main fragment.
What is the solution to display the main fragment ?

I've tried overriding *onBackPressed()* as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Fragment mainFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .show(mainFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace your fragment you must add it to the back stack so that the transaction can be reversible and you can bring back the previous fragment.

```java
public void diplayFragmentB() {
    // Not really necessary fragment manager can handle it
//  Fragment mainFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
//     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//             .hide(mainFragment) 
//             .commit();

    // In documentation, it is recommended to pass the class as a parameter instead of instance
    // FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentB.class, null)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        // Since you have only one level you can use directly popBackStack()
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Try this code and give me a feedback for further help.

Comment: You are welcome. I moved the fragmentManager assignment above the if statement. This way is better. BTW thanks for the spelling correction :) .